# Como puedo generar una funcion recursiva con un número

Tags: javascript, recursión

Tengo este código, pero no me sale la respuesta, intenté también que me saliera en la consola pero no me sirvió, también quería que saliera el código como está el script en la página, ya sea a un lado o que no sea tan relevante gracias.

```js
function numerica(x){
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    if (x === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return x + numerica(--x)
    }
    alert("LA RECURSION EN NUMEROS ES:" + numerica);
}
```

```html
 

<p>INGRESE EL NUMERO <input type="number" id="x" min="0" max="99"></p>
<input type="button" onclick="numerica()" value="CALCULAR">
</br>
```

Comment: Que se supone debe hacer esa función?

Comment: Hola darkman, independientemente de cualquier otro error, la ejecución de tu código jamas pasa por el **alert**, ya que está después de un bloque **if/else** con **return**, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Una función recursiva, que haga ¿que?

Comment: Podrías explicar claramente que necesitas que haga la función?, gracias.

Comment: La recursion no te va a funcionar porque a "x" la estas declarando y asignando valor y la verdad tienes x por todos lados. Deberías quitar la primera línea e invocar a la función la primera vez con el valor del id.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente buscas sumar los números consecutivos desde N hasta 1, podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('x')

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', () => { 
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = numerica(parseInt(input.value))
})

function numerica(x) {
  if(x == 0) return x
  return x + numerica(--x)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>INGRESE EL NUMERO <input type="number" id="x" min="0" max="99"></p>
  <input type="button" id="calc" value="CALCULAR">
  <h3>RESULT: <span id="result"></span></h3>
  </br>
  <script src="scripts2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Añadí varios id's para poder llamarlos desde JS. Al clickear en 'calcular' se llama a la función recursivamente pasando como parámetros el valor del input, una vez hecho esto se escribe el resultado en un `<SPAN>`.

Y por favor agrega más detalles a la pregunta sino los demás tenemos que estar adivinando que es lo que buscas... saludos.